# Adding a marker on the openlayers gives a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to add a marker to our map project and it dosen't seem to be working. 
The I am working the first time with ol and the project was written by another guy.

So here we go. 
I have an area on a map and some objects on the area. The area has a vector circle but the objects don't have any indicators, so we decided to add them a bit a crude way.

Basically, i added an eventListener in the menu and onClick it already centers me to the object. 
I added the following code from the docs (we are working with ol4) and it gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined` 
Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

```
var marker = new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
                   ol.proj.fromLonLat([coords])
                    ),
                });
marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
                        src: '/kaart/images/indicator.svg'
                    }))
                }));
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                    features: [marker]
                });
var markerVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: vectorSource,
                });
map.addLayer(marker);
```

Comment: Can you include the code where the error is occurring (the code you have provided doesn't use addLayer).

Comment: @Mike yeah, sorry i copied the wrong one. Changed it. Thank you.

Comment: Have you defined `map` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, it is.
```this.map = new ol.Map({ ... ```

Comment: Since it seems to be undefined when you call `addLayer` is the definition in scope and made before you use it?